# Can I use Java Stream and support Android 5.1 as well?

Tags: java, android, java-8

I used Java 1.8+ feature of Stream/filter in my android app code, it worked on the virtual device with API 26 (android 8.0) but didn't work on AVD with API 22 (Android 5.1). My android phone is 5.1

Can I have Java 1.8+ feature in my code AND the code support Android 5.1 (API 22) at the same time?

my module's buold.gradle looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.entrepidea.imgurdnloadr"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't use Java 8 streams on API level 22. The requirement for availability of streams is minSdkVersion=24. You can work with one of the backports though: [LSA](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API), [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/)

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out